# ISeries Tables/Views not showing up in Crystal Reports 2013

Tags: crystal-reports, ibm-midrange, iseries-navigator

I have an iSeries server running v5r4. I have several tables and views that I have created over the past couple of years on the server. I have used them with no problem in the past, yet suddenly most of the tables and views in a Schema that I created are not showing up this morning in Crystal Reports.  The only ones that I can see are those owned by QSECOFR. I must have been logged in that way when I created those 5 tables. I can see all of the tables and views in that schema in iSeries Navigator. I'm not sure when the problem started, but this is the first time I noticed it. I tried running a report using one of the views from the schema, and it runs fine. When I look at the links for that report, I see the view that I created. When I look at the database tables and try to locate that view within the Schema, it isn't showing up. Views and tables are both checked in the options of Crystal Reports. I can see the views and tables for the ERP software, just not the Schema that I created.

I'm at a loss as to what could have happened. I am the only one who has access to change anything on the server or in Crystal Reports. As far as I know, I haven't changed any of the security settings on the iSeries. I'm logged into iSeries Navigator and Crystal Reports as myself (Karen). The permissions on individual views/tables within the Schema give me "All" authority. That Schema is in the library list on the ODBC Connection. I'm using the iSeries Access ODBC Driver.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Been a long time since I've been in Crystal but have you checked on any filters on table and schema names?

Comment: Yes. No filters on any of the tables.

Comment: If you connect from Crystal as QSECOFR does it work?

Comment: Tried it and it does work as QSECOFR. Thanks for the help. I have no idea what might have changed (I always login to Crystal as Karen), but this will get me by until I can figure it out.

Comment: grant read on filename to username

Comment: edtobjaut user * use   should be enough to read from a view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be aware that **no user objects** should be owned by QSECOFR (nor by any IBM Q* profile). [Many Information Center references](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/search/qsecofr%20and%20owner%20and%20object?scope=ssw_ibm_i_72&lang=en) note that recommendation. And QSECOFR should not be used as a logon except as directed or documented by IBM.

If possible, change the ownership to a different profile that has no purpose other than to act as an owner. Assign a *AUTL for the objects and grant authority through it to the users, perhaps initially by granting *PUBLIC *CHANGE in the *AUTL.

---

Owners of objects should not have special authorities. QSECOFR always has all special authorities and cannot be changed. It can be special authorities, most especially *ALLOBJ, that interfere with network accesses. Removing the special authority from the owner or setting a different owner profile might be needed, and it's often a useful test when trying to determine problem causes.

Comment: I wanted to say that too but I'd bet it wasn't quite qsecofr but rather a profile with *all object authority.

Comment: @danny117 That's a useful point. I'll add it to the answer for future reference.